# Run replace command on svn:externals (python)

Tags: python, svn, externals

I am currently writing a python script which needs to run a sed command to replace stuff from the svn:externals data.
I tried to run sed on "svn propedit svn:externals ." but the outcome is not the one expected.

Does anyone know how to do this ?

Comment: You should post the non-working sed/svn command to get better answers. Otherwise, all answers are just guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, don't use `sed`. Use Python's string methods or the `re` module.

Second, I recommend to run `svn propget ...` first, to fetch the old value. Then, you manipulate it (within Python, no need to run `sed`). Finally, you run `svn propset`.

Alternatively, you could run a second Python script as editor for `svn propedit`. Here, too, you don't need sed if you already have Python.